# Getting empty "data": [ ] from facebook graph with read_stream permission

Tags: c#, facebook, json, facebook-graph-api

I'm getting empty  "data": [   ] from **json facebook graph** when i'm using **read_stream** premission

**BUT** with a Token that i took from this page: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/#auth

I am getting **full Data**

They both have the same **read_stream** permission....

What to do?  I understand that tokens are temporary

**BTW: is't safe to post the Tokens?**

**UPDATE!! I don't have *bookmarked:1* in the BAD Token.. how do i get it?**

exmaple::

**BAD not working Token:**

https://graph.facebook.com/717054208/links&fields=link,picture,id,name?access_token=AAABkiSd72F4BAB8lZB6ZBzBv7ZChNDINOD60tmsxrxmjCDzOOD6XDrnFPuA1Es0Lp5GDFHUsGkz7WnIgYxr8GBYZBtOtrHipV0AQzTOVFAZDZD

> { data: [ { installed: 1, read_stream: 1, user_status: 1, bookmarked:
> 1 } ] }

.

.

**GOOD working token:**

https://graph.facebook.com/717054208/links&fields=link,picture,id,name?access_token=AAAAAAITEghMBABD81Bg6CZCCWkHPfgE0pQN3bQmGdsZBeNcEwVmEuluyWaon7ZBUXhjflgiWFQzfyPFTlyPVAKvhit15bhDAcIrl3gCsgZDZD

> { data: [ { installed: 1, read_stream: 1, user_status: 1, bookmarked:
> 1 } ] }

**As you can see it's the same premissions!!!**

and it's not working....

**Please look on the GOOD token... it's has the same premissions.....**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's was a know Bug in Facebook API that happened randomly.

It's Now fixed After I talked with the Support dev

Thanks for all!

Answer (score 0):

You've got lots more permissions on the [second token](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/access_token?q=AAAAAAITEghMBABD81Bg6CZCCWkHPfgE0pQN3bQmGdsZBeNcEwVmEuluyWaon7ZBUXhjflgiWFQzfyPFTlyPVAKvhit15bhDAcIrl3gCsgZDZD) than on the [first token](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/access_token?q=AAABkiSd72F4BANDddHRuaZAyXLxmHzFFPC57Pnmb9vRkZBfZCr9py146fyEJZBNveiCq702thsAhZClYr3UHGKZCJS4PZBZCxpk9nZAqenZAFfEgZDZD) you listed in your example above.

It does not look like the [object_id you are querying](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=717054208) is your own profile, so you probably need a token like `friends_activies`.

BTW: You've got the permissions of your tokens reversed in your example above.

Comment: friends_activities: 1 it's ON.. i did all this premission to see if this is the problem.

Comment: It's not that then. You'll need to keep adding permissions one by one until you get it.

Comment: BTW, you really don't want an active access token floating around the 'net with a `manage_pages` or `read_messages` permissions.

Comment: Can you see the problem now... the premissions are the same...
and for some reason it's still not working...

Comment: Add a longer limit; i.e ask for `/me/links?limit=999`

Comment: this is not the problem... as you can see it's still not working...
https://graph.facebook.com/717054208/links&limit=999&fields=link,picture,id,name?access_token=AAABkiSd72F4BAB8lZB6ZBzBv7ZChNDINOD60tmsxrxmjCDzOOD6XDrnFPuA1Es0Lp5GDFHUsGkz7WnIgYxr8GBYZBtOtrHipV0AQzTOVFAZDZD

Comment: You had it working. You just have to find which permission you need.